# How to study the convergence of this series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

> Is convergent series?
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^∞{{1}\over{n^2+2\sqrt{n}-21}}.$$

Comment: What have you tried?  What do the first several terms look like?  Can you compare it to a similar series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: How does $\dfrac1{n^2+2\sqrt{n}-21}$ compare with $\dfrac1{n^2}$ when $n\ge 121$, say?

The key idea here is that the $n^2$ term is the dominant term in the denominator, so for large $n$ the denominator ought to behave much like $n^2$.

Comment: This series converges?

Comment: @user62189: Yes, by comparison with the convergent series $\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{n^2}$.